# Remove time slot if all employees are busy (assigned to a appointment)

Tags: sql

I have a calendar, which the customers will use to choose a date, when the date is chosen a popup appears with a dropdown menu with the working hours, if all employees are busy at the particular time I want it to be removed from the drop down menu

My tables:

```
schedule (ID, date, start_time,end_time,Customerid) 
appointment_Staff (id, ScheduleID, staffID,AdminID) 
working_Hours (id,start_time,end_time)
```

what I have so far :

```
SELECT WorkingHours 
FROM WorkingHours
EXCEPT
(
    SELECT StartTime 
    FROM Assign_Staff,Schedule1 
    WHERE Assign_Staff.ScheduleId = Schedule1.ScheduleID 
    AND EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT ScheduleID, StartTime 
        FROM Schedule1 
        WHERE Date='2016-08-16'
    )
)

SELECT DISTINCT StaffID, WorkingHours 
FROM Staff, WorkingHours
EXCEPT
(
    SELECT StaffID, StartTime 
    FROM Assign_Staff, Schedule1 
    WHERE Assign_Staff.ScheduleId = Schedule1.ScheduleID 
    AND EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT ScheduleID, StartTime 
        FROM Schedule1 
        WHERE Date='2016-08-16'
    )
)
```

can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: please look [HERE](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to improve the question

Comment: Could you show us some sample content of your tables?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?